# Input in Gogland not work

Tags: go, goland

I have a simple code in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    var text string
    fmt.Print("Enter your text: ")
    scanner.Scan()
    text = scanner.Text()
    fmt.Println("Your text was: ", text)
}
```

When I run the code in my terminal or using Run mode in Gogland, work perfectly.

But, when I run the same code in Gogland by Debug mode, even if I typed `Enter`, keeps reading the input.

[image]

How to fix it? Or it's a bug? I'm using the Gogland 1.0 EAP.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue for *Gogland-172.3757.2*, it is defenetly a bug.

Try to create the new one at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/GO

Answer (score 0):

By default the application does not run in a true terminal.  See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4179 for details.